# Custom Authentication for Apps "Like Facebook - Github Authentication"

Tags: android, api, security, authentication, encryption

Facebook, GitHub, Instagram, Twitter ... etc. has a special button that you can use to create accounts and you will log in to applications through your account on their platforms.
I tried hard to build the same button and add the ability to log in through my app.
I managed to build a method but I don't think it's very secure either. I'd like to explore some potential vulnerabilities or scenarios.
The project is currently for Android only and I want to develop it to work with browsers in the future
The button works well and I built four applications through this button and logged in through it via Firebase .
Here I have attached my code:

> Here is the main application code   'A'

```
 if (IsCurrentUserExist(mAuth.getUid()) && IsCertifiedCall() && NoRootApp()){

                    user_doc = db.collection("users").document(Objects.requireNonNull(mAuth.getUid()));
                    user_doc.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {


                            String pass = snapshot.getString("AppAuthenticationPassword");
                            String email = snapshot.getString("x4loopEmail");
                            String name = snapshot.getString("name");
                            String DecodingCode= snapshot.getString("Decrypt-Code");
                            String profile_image = snapshot.getString("profile_image");

                            if (snapshot.contains("AppAuthenticationPassword")){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getCalledPackage(true,this));
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                intent.putExtra("x4loopEmail",email);
                                intent.putExtra("password",pass);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();

                            }

                            else {
                                String Pass =  generateRandomPassword(36) ;
                                user_doc.update("AppAuthenticationPassword" ,Pass).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                        String Emails =  mAuth.getUid() + "x-4loop@"  + RandomEmailDomain(5) + ".chat4loop" ;
                                        user_doc.update("x4loopEmail" , Emails ).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                                Intent intent = new Intent("ivi.messenger.x4loop.ui.register.RegisterActivity");
                                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                                intent.putExtra("x4loop-email",Emails);
                                                intent.putExtra("password",Pass);
                                                intent.putExtra("name",name);
                                               intent.putExtra("profile_image",profile_image);
                                                intent.putExtra("x-4loop",mAuth.getUid());
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                                finish();

                                            }
                                        });

                                    }
                                });
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    notify.setText("Sign in first");
                    CreateAccountButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
```

}

> Second app  'B'

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.hasExtra("x4loop-email") && intent.hasExtra("x4loop-email")) {
    emailInput = intent.getStringExtra("x4loop-email");
    passwordInput = intent.getStringExtra("AppAuthenticationPassword");
    isLogedIn = intent.getBooleanExtra("IsLogedIn", false);
    usernamedInput = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    profile_image = intent.getStringExtra("profile_image");
    IdoUid = intent.getStringExtra("IdoUid");
    DecryptC = intent.getStringExtra("Decrypt-Code");

    getIntent().removeExtra("x4loop-email");
    getIntent().removeExtra("password");
    getIntent().removeExtra("Decrypt-Code");
    getIntent().removeExtra("name");
    getIntent().removeExtra("profile_image");


    registerViewModel.register(emailInput, DecryptThisCodeAsPassword(DecryptC , passwordInput ) ,usernamedInput , profile_image , IdoUid);
    subscribeObservers();
}
```

The password is encrypted in the databases and is decrypted in the second and first application directly
This code is just for you to understand how the app works.

But because of the ease of the code, I feel insecure, even though I have implemented many things to secure the two applications well.
Also in the Firebase functions, there is a function that encrypts and decrypts each new password that is stored in the database, and the decryption code is random, so no one can decrypt it'almost'.
No one can obtain the login data unless he is logged into the application.

I also share the user's picture, name and e-mail with the new application, but the second application can read the password explicitly, and developers can easily save the password in their databases because of the easy way to transfer data between the two applications.
Are there better methods than what I do!
"I don't want a `Firebase CustomToken`" , Because Firebase Requires `AdminSDK` and It is not compatible with my app.

[image]

Comment: Sharing same password between two applications is not the best approach. That's why passwords are usually stored using one-way cryptographic key derivation functions. Twitter, FB and other social media utilize backend OpenID Connect flow (https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-native-sso-1_0.html), (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview).

Comment: In my application, the password will not be obtained if the user is not logged in, and he will only get the password for his account. Is this a danger to the user?

Comment: I'm thinking of the following threats: the method for sharing a password (or the password itself) must be exposed to other applications (including those malicious ones). The second issue is password synchronization: how to enforce changing password in all apps when it's changed in the first one, i.e. due to leakage. There may be more, connected with the way the password is stored in the app (which storage is used).

Comment: The main application does not contain a password, there is only an account creation through the email link and you can only change the email, there are no passwords in the main application and the second also

Comment: "The password is encrypted in the databases and is decrypted in the second and first application directly " - sorry, I've have must misunderstood this, then.

Comment: I don't think you misunderstood me, but there is a password that is generated automatically when a second application connects to the main application, which passes through the two applications, can any application be intercepted and the password obtained?